# Output not getting print after matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, matrix-multiplication

In the code below, my aim is to multiply two matrices reflect[3][3] and mat[3][s] where s can be any value 0-10. Here the statement (A) and (B) is not getting printed, please tell me why??

```
#include<iostream>
# include<math.h>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int mat[10][10];
int result[3][10];
int reflect[3][3]= {1,0,5,0,1,5,0,0,1};
int i , j,k,s;
void multiply_matrix(int A[3][3], int B[3][10])
{
    
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        for( j=0; j<10; j++)
            result[i][j] = 0;
                
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                 result[i][j]=result[i][j]+(A[i][k]*B[k][j]) ;
            }
            cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";//------(1)
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

 cout<<"Multiplication after matrix: "<<endl;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<s; j++)
            {
                cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";//------(B)
            }
        cout<<endl;;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i, j,s;

    cout<<"Enter the sides of polygon :\n";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"Enter the coordinates of polygon :\n";

    cout<<"Enter x coordinates ";
    for(i=0; i<s; i++)
        cin>>mat[0][i];

    cout<<"Enter y coordinates ";
    for(i=0; i<s; i++)
        cin>>mat[1][i];
        
        cout<<"\n\n";

    for(i=0; i<s; i++)
        mat[2][i] = 1;

 cout<<"MAt: "<<endl;
    
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<s; j++)
            {
                cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
            }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    multiply_matrix(reflect, mat);
    cout<<"End"<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have attached a sample output image for reference:
[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr05p.png)

I am a newbie and have tried various things but I am just not able to figure my mistake. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try debugging the code? Do not post text as images.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `s` in your code. Globally:

```
int i , j,k,s;
```

And in `main`:

```
int i, j,s;
```

The one in main you assign a value read from user input, but the global one is `0` always. `multiply_matrix` uses the global one, hence this loops have zero iterations:

> ```
>     for (j = 0; j < s; j++)
>     {
>         result[i][j] = 0;
>         for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
>         {
>              result[i][j]=result[i][j]+(A[i][k]*B[k][j]) ;
>         }
>         cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";//------(1)
>     }
> ```

and

> ```
>     for(j=0; j<s; j++)
>         {
>             cout<<result[i][j]<<" ";//------(B)
>         }
> ```